# Test Accuracy for Unbalanced Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, unbalanced-classes

I have a binary, highly unbalanced dataset with a ratio of 1:20 between the two classes. Now to account for this, I have constructed mini-batches with equal ratio between the two classes, in order to artificially balance the ratio. My current algorithm samples the underlying classes and feeds that into the neural network followed with back-propagation.

**Questions:**

1) With regards to my test-set, I'm just wondering should my test-set be randomly selected (results in a very fuzzy graph) or should I keep my test-set constant (as in without random sampling of the entire test set)?

2) What are the shortcomings between each approach & which is more valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the test set constant to be able to compare performance between different runs, paramatrisations and algorithms. Also, you should probably think of it as a validation set and not a test set.

The difference being that you use the validation set to keep adjusting your methods and algorithms and only when you are done do you use your test set (only once) to access the performance you can expect on unseen data.

A bit off-topic but consider not artificially balancing your training set, especially if the data in the real world will not be balanced. Instead use precision, recall and the f1 score to assess your performance and move your decision threshold to best meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough input. Will look into other evaluation methods